# Should I use "is" or "are" after "conclusion"?

Tags: nouns, subject-verb-agreement, noun-phrases, countable-nouns

1. > Conclusion **is** as follows:
2. > Conclusion **are** as follows:

Should it be ***is*** or ***are***?

Does this use of *conclusion* have an irregular plural like *aircraft* or *series*?

Are there any other problems with the grammar here?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, welcome to ELL. You probably want to wait a couple of days before choosing an answer. You might get better or more helpful ones!

Comment: What's the rest of the sentence?  Context, as always, means a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The word *conclusion* can refer to either:

> 1.1  **The summing-up of an argument or text**:
>
> > *in the conclusion we highlight these and other important issues*

or

> 2.0  **A judgement or decision reached by reasoning**:
>
> > *each research group came to a similar conclusion*

In other words it can be the last section of a piece of writing, or it can be a decision you make after thinking about something. Both of these uses of the word *conclusion* are **countable**. They also use regular plurals.

This means that if we are talking about two or more sections or decisions we need to use the plural form:

- conclusion**s**

If we are talking about one conclusion, then as with all singular English noun phrases we must use a Determiner (a word like *a, the, this, that, my, one, two, no*). In the Original Poster's example, then if we are talking about the last section of a piece of writing, we probably want to use *the* as a Determiner. There is only one conclusion in the piece of writing and everyone knows which one we are talking about:

- The conclusion

However, if we are talking about the idea(s) we have after thinking about something, or discussing it, then we might also expect to see a possessive pronoun as Determiner:

- **The / Our / My / The team's** conclusion is as follows ...
- **The / Our / My / The team's** conclusions are as follows ...

Of course, where *conclusion* is singular we expect *is*, and when it is plural (conclusion**s**), we expect *are*.

Answer (score 0):

It's a regular plural. These are correct:

> The conclusion is as follows:
>
> The conclusions are as follows: